# Passing parameters from python to applescript

Tags: parameters, applescript, popen

I am trying to run an applescript app with a python program so that python sends the applescript app parameters

I've searched the Internet  and many pages to StackOverflow and I've found that this code should work. 
This is a trial to try and figure out how it works.

```
args = "/Users/user/Documents/Scripts/Parameters.app/Contents/MacOS/applet -Profile /Volumes/MM/FF"
FFProcess = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(args)+ [" Heello"])
```

In the applescript app I have

```
on run argv
display dialog "hello" & argv
end run
```

I expected to see hello -Profile /Volumes/MM/FF Heello in the dialog or maybe
hello Heello

What I actually got was hellocurrent application

Would really appreciate knowing what I'm doing wrong.
Blessings

Comment: `on run argv` only works for AppleScript files run via `osascript`, not for AppleScript applets.

Comment: Thanks. Is there another way to pick up a parameter in an applescript from another executable. What I really want at this stage is to run the applescript file with Thunderbird to open an https link.. THunderbird will send the link to the applescript program but how could the applescript pick it up?

Comment: Put an `on open location theURL…end open location` handler in your applet (you’ll need to give it a custom bundle ID and save it as stay-open) to allow it to handle GET URL events, and run `Popen(['/usr/bin/open', '-b', bundleid, url])…` to open a URL from Python. That should work.